# The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'amazonaws.com' contains one or more invalid characters

Tags: security, next.js, http-headers

I am using next@12 to generate the CSP using the next.config.js and this is the error I receive inside my console:

> The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'amazonaws.com' contains
> one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or
> dashes '-' are allowed in directive names.

Here is the header I'm using:

```
  {
    key: "Content-Security-Policy",
    value: "amazonaws.com *.amazonaws.com cloudinary.com *.cloudinary.com",
  },
```

According to [web.dev](https://web.dev/measure/):

> script-src directive is missing. This can allow the execution of
> unsafe scripts.
>
> Missing object-src allows the injection of plugins that execute unsafe
> scripts.  Consider setting object-src to 'none' if you can.

I try to set there parameters but It crashes my site. I'm probably doing it wrong. Any idea how to go about setting these rightly?

Comment: You have to include a policy directive before the domains, e.g. `value: "default-src amazonaws.com *.amazonaws.com cloudinary.com *.cloudinary.com"`